# MVC - HTTP Response Asynchronous race on C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this GET method, it retrieves a Post resource containing the post information.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<PostResource> GetOneAsync(int id)
        {
            var post = await _postService.GetSingleAsync(id);

            var resource = _mapper.Map<Post, PostResource>(post);
            return resource;
        }
```

This is what you get when you request GET '/api/posts/id', it includes the User resource which created the Post.

```
{
    "id": 103,
    "title": "¿Te sueles despetar por la noche?",
    "description": "",
    "pay": 1.77,
    "pubDate": "2020-02-27 03:05:10-05",
    "user": {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Piter",
        "surname": "Cueva",
        "dni": "19482984",
        "birth": "18/8/1888",
        "email": "pitercueva@gmail.com",
        "password": "clavesegura"
    }
}
```

I have this PUT method. After i insert a new Post, i want to return the updated Post resource with a [200 OK] status response. I use the exact same logic on the previous request (get by id).

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync(int id, SavePostResource resource)
        {
            var post = _mapper.Map<SavePostResource, Post>(resource);
            var result = await _postService.UpdateAsync(id, post);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(result.Message);
            }   

            var resultUpdated = await _postService.GetSingleAsync(id);
            var postUpdated = _mapper.Map<Post, PostResource>(resultUpdated );
            return Ok(postUpdated);
        }
```

What i expect is the same JSON answer i received previously. However, i'm getting this null field on User on the [200 OK] status response:

```
{
    "id": 103,
    "title": "¿Te sueles despetar por la noche?",
    "description": "",
    "pay": 1.77,
    "pubDate": "2020-02-27 03:05:10-05",
    "user": null
}
```

The Post DOES get stored, because when i call GET '/api/posts/id' later, the new post appears there with it's User just fine, no nulls, but i also want to show the user on the [200 OK] status response when i do the PUT request.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the await keyword and returning the old resource before the new resource reached the database. How should i approach this problem? How can i make sure the:

**await _postService.UpdateAsync(id, post);**

Happens before the:

**await _postService.GetSingleAsync(id);**

Comment: It has nothing to do with async because you are correctly awaiting the response. My guess is that your automapper mapping is messing up the user object. Either you don't have a property named User on SavePostResource class or your mapping is not correctly defined. Can you post your auto mapper mappings?

Comment: @Marko Sure, but before i do, i want to ask something. If it was the SavePostResource or the Mapping, the Post with it's User wouldn't be stored at all, right?. But that's not the case, after i get this null in the PUT 200 response, i can call GET /api/posts and the new post will appear just fine with it's User. It seems like the problem is within this PutAsync function.

Comment: If you await the asynchronous method in .net, it does not run parallel to the rest of your code. All it does is free up the resource/thread to do other work. The code execution is still synchronous - the next line in your code will not execute until the previous one is done. In my opinion, it is not possible that this is some sort of racing condition.

Comment: Can you try remove the `async Task` syntax for those 2 API and test again ? It seems not like async/await issue, it's more like _postService or _mapper causes the inconsistent result.

Comment: @nwpie Wish i could but i have other 4 layers of async dependency which i shouldn't be touching.

Comment: In fact, just need adjust a little bit, like this

 `await _postService.GetSingleAsync(id)` => `_postService.GetSingleAsync(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Not necessary to modify every layers' interface or behavior.

Comment: @nwpie you were right, that allowed me to remove `async Task` without touching other layers. However, the status response still shows User as null.

Comment: @nwpie You should never use GetAwaiter().GetResult() to make async method synchronous as it is not thread safe and it can cause deadlocks. For more info see: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Marko thanks for this reminder. I'm not telling the poster to follow what I said, just try telling him/her to test in another way to prove its basically not an async/await issue.

Comment: @nwpie Yup that makes sense I just don't want him to open another can of worms... :)

Comment: @Bata so, now you know its not async/await, racing issue. You can then focus on `_postService` and `_mapper` for further testing.